# What is the raw form of a compressed image file format(jpeg, PNG , gif)?

Tags: compression, image-compression, information-theory

As we know jpeg , PNG , gif are all compressed file formats, my question is what is the original source of input we provide to these compression algorithms and in which form a image data is stored before it gets converted into one of these file formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends.

PNG is generally lossless, but it does have a limit on the number of bits/pixel. GIF turns out to be lossless, too, but it is more complicated to get a high number of colors. These formats are still compressed, but use a compression that doesn't lose data.

JPEG is lossy. If you save as a JPEG, you will not be able to revert back to another format without losing some clarity. By representing the data as equations it can get quite small, but it can start to look "blurry" as the approximations get worse.

There are other images formats, like TIFF, RAW and BMP, which generally don't do any compression, although they are really more like containers and technically can contain compressed data, but they usually don't.

The original, uncompressed, data depends on what generates it.  A photoshop file will save as a PSD but internally may represent it differently in memory. Every digital camera may have a different way of laying out its internal memory, and the photo sensors tend to map 1 to 1 from a sensor to a memory location of a set number of bits.

The common pattern, however, is that each pixel of the image is stored as 3 (sometimes 4) color values, each one between 8 and 16 bits. The 3 values may represent Red, Green and Blue, or alternatively Hue, Saturation and Value. For design, it could be CMYK (Cyan, Magenta, Yellow and blacK). There could also be an alpha value. It's unusual to use more than 16 bits for each color channel and most common to use 8. Using 12 bits is considered by most to be full color, but that doesn't align very well on 32 bit or even 64 bit machines. Still, 12 bit is used sometimes in digital video signals since when broadcast serially the color values don't need to fit into words.

Different formats will go in a different order. Usually rows first, but some formats start at the bottom row and some start at the top.

So, the real answer is it depends on what the particular compressor is looking for. Most software that saves as JPEG or PNG will accept multiple formats and the most common is probably 32bit/pixels with 8 bytes each for RGB (red, green, blue) and one either unused or alpha. It will need width and height of the image so the image data should be width*height*4 in bytes. You generally pass in a defined constant that tells it the byte order: RBGA, ARGB, BGR, RGB, etc.

Comment: I didn't touch on non-full color images. Of course, there are palettes and lower bits/pixel in some cases.